# Convert a .rtf into a mac .r resource, in a scriptable way

Tags: macos, resources, rtf, format-conversion

I currently have a SLA in a .rtf format, which is to be integrated into .dmg using the intermediary .r mac resource format, which is used by the Rez utility. I had already done it by hand once, but updates made to the .rtf file are overwhelming to propagate to the disk image, and error-prone. I would like to automate this task, which could also help adding other languages or variants.

How could the process of .rtf to .r text conversion be automated?

Thanks.

Comment: I would have added the "rez" stackoverflow tag to this question, which is missing, but my reputation is too low for creating a new tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `unrtf` port (from macports), then format the lines, heading and tail with a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Only because I didn't fully understand how the accepted answer actually achieved the goal, I use a combination of a script to generate the hex encoding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Makes resource (.r) text from binaries.

def usage
  puts "usage: #{$0} infile"
  puts ""
  puts "  infile   The file to convert (the output will go to stdout)"
  exit 1
end

infile = ARGV[0]    || usage

data = File.read(infile)
data.bytes.each_slice(16) do |slice|
  hex = slice.each_slice(2).map { |pair| pair.pack('C*').unpack('H*')[0] }.join(' ')

  # We could put the comments in too, but it probably isn't a big deal.
  puts "\t$\"#{hex}\""
end
```

The output of this is inserted into a variable during the build and then the variable ends up in a template (we're using Ant to do this, but the specifics aren't particularly interesting):

```
data 'RTF ' (5000, "English SLA") {
@english.licence@
};
```

The one bit of this which did take quite a while to figure out is that `'RTF '` can be used for the resource directly. The Apple docs say to separately insert `'TEXT'` (with just the plain text) and `'styl'` (with just the style). There are tools to do this of course, but it was one more tool to run and I could never figure out how to make hyperlinks work in the resulting DMG. With `'RTF '`, hyperlinks just work.

Hoping that this saves someone time in the future.